# Have conditional text display based on the value in a cookie

Tags: cookies, conditional-statements

I want to have a sentence appear at the near the bottom (in the center) of the page based on a value in a cookie.  For instance, if the value in readCookie("my.common.name") is KPT, then I would like the sentence, "Thank you for visiting our sunny site" at the bottom of the page. If the value were PBTJ then I would want the sentence, "Call us at 888-888-8888." instead.

Could someone help with this?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Javascript preferably